# reactive cocoa: replay if getting active

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

i have a singleton with a property KGTour *tour;
the singleton has a RACReplaySubject *tourChangedSubject that sends the tour object if it gets set.

```
[mySingleton startTour:aNewTourObject];
```

in my singleton's custom setter:

```
- (void)startTour:(KGTour *)tour {
    [self.tourChangedSubject sendNext:tour];
}
```

then i have a viewModel that - when initialized - replays the last tour:

```
[[mySingleton.tourChangedSubject replayLast]] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    ...
}];
```

this works as expected and everything is fine for now.

BUT: my goal is to replay this tour only if my viewModel is active and another property is set to true.
so i created a signal telling me when "ready" (if active and isLoaded are true):

```
self.isLoadedSignal = [RACObserve(self, isLoaded)
    filter:^(NSNumber *loaded) {
        return loaded.boolValue;
    }];
self.isActiveSignal = [RACObserve(self, isActive)
    filter:^(NSNumber *active) {
        return active.boolValue;
    }];

RACSignal *readySignal = [self.isActiveSignal
    flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        @strongify(self);
        return self.mapIsLoadedSignal;
    }];
```

the viewModel may toggle its active state.
after it gets active again, i want to get the latest tour and do something.

e.g. the viewModel was active some seconds, now its active flag get set to false. if inactive, updating the singleton's tour property (and emitting a tourChangedSubject) should not bother the inactive viewModel. but if the viewModel gets active again, it should replay the last tour to update some UI of the viewModel.

i really like RAC but i have my troubles really getting into it, so any hints would be greatly appreciated!

cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will create `lastTourIfReadySignal` which will send latest value of `tourChangedSubject` if view model `isLoaded` and `isActive`.

```
RACSignal* isReadySignal = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, isLoaded),
                                                       RACObserve(self, isActive)]]
                            and];

RACSignal* lastTourIfReadySignal = [[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[mySingleton.tourChangedSubject, 
                                                               isReadySignal]]
                                    filter:^BOOL(RACTuple* tuple) {
                                        return [tuple.second boolValue];
                                    }]
                                    map:^id(RACTuple* tuple) {
                                        return tuple.first;
                                    }];
```

Comment: thanks, but the lastTourIfReadySignal fires immediately when the tourChangedSubject sends a tour (weird, but "tuple.second.boolValue" is true although "active" is NO). 


i am trying to replay the last tour if the viewModel changes it's state to active=YES (and if isLoaded=YES). active may toggle many times, while isLoaded will just change once (to YES). not very good in explaning the case, but hopefully you understand this usecase...

Comment: lastTourIfReadySignal should fire only if the viewModel isActive and isLoaded. if it is inactive and mySingleton gets a new KGTour object, the lastTourIfReadySignal should fire after the viewModel isActive again...

Comment: Yes, I understood your use case, and I can't see why proposed solution would not work..  How do you define `isLoaded` and `isActive` ?